# Does a Ghanaian UK resident need a Belgian transit visa?

Tags: transit-visas, belgium, uk-residents, ghanaian-citizens

I am a Ghanaian with a UK Biometric Residence Permit. I wish to travel to Ghana through Belgium using Air Brussels.

Do l need a transit visa if l will not be going outside the airport when I get to Belgium please?

Answer (score 4):

It would appear that you do need a visa.

“Transiting without a visa is possible for:

- Nationals of Ghana arriving from a non-Schengen Member State with a confirmed onward ticket for a flight within 24 hours to a third country which is not a Schengen Member State. They must:
- have a visa issued by Bulgaria, Canada, Croatia, Cyprus, Ireland (Rep.), Japan, Romania, or USA, and
- stay in the international transit area of the airport, and
- have documents required for the next destination.”

Source Timatic: https://www.timaticweb2.com/integration/external?ref=d975cfc59f5c0abd06d16e872198110b&clear=true

The UK is not among the countries whose visa holders or residents are exempt from securing a transit visa.

Comment: Thank u very much. I m grateful

Answer (score 1):

Yes, indeed you need one.

Here are the requirements ( from [VisaGuide.world](https://visaguide.world/europe/belgium-visa/transit-visa/#:%7E:text=A%20transit%20visa%20allows%20you,wait%20for%20your%20next%20flight.)) :

1. Schedule an appointment by contacting the Belgium embassy or the consulate. If there is no Belgian embassy/consulate, you have to find out where they have outsourced visa submissions. It could be the embassy or consulate of another country or a visa application center
2. Fill the Belgium transit visa application form. The visa application form should be available online at the website of the embassy/consulate or visa application center. Alternatively, you may have to go pick up a physical copy of the form at their offices.
3. Prepare the required documents. Collect the required documents for a Belgium transit visa application.
4. Be present at your appointment and bring with you the required documents.
5. Pay the visa fee.

There is more information in [SchengenVisaInfo](https://www.schengenvisainfo.com/belgium-visa/) and [VisaGuide.world](https://visaguide.world/europe/belgium-visa/transit-visa/#:%7E:text=A%20transit%20visa%20allows%20you,wait%20for%20your%20next%20flight.)